# Grammatical correctness of 〜好きくない

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, adjectives, i-adjectives, role-language

I saw 未来のミライ the other day. The boy said 〜好きくない regarding many people. Was he making a grammar mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

好きくない is indeed not proper grammar. It is sometimes used by children (and hence in fiction for children or childlike characters), reanalyzing 好き which should be a *na*-adjective 好き（な） as an *i*-adjective *好きい, hence *好きくない or *好きかった.

Comment: https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Comment: @JACK Not sure what you're implying with this link, but considering your deleted answer you might have missed that the entry says "grammatically incorrect negation of 好き".

Comment: Exactly what I did.

Comment: Cool, that's what I suspected, but if I recall correctly, one of the parents said it as well. I think they were just quoting the boy affectionately.